# Как заставить рандом давать вещественные числа?

Tags: php, php7, php5, php7.2

Что можно сделать?

```
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $arr[$i] = float(rand(1, 100));
    echo $arr[$i].'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

На вскидку несколько вариантов:

1. `$rand = rand(15,25)/10;`
2. Либо в мануале php представлена такая функция:

   `function random_float ($min,$max) {
      return ($min+lcg_value()*(abs($max-$min)));
   }`

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $arr[$i] = (float)rand(1, 100); //<--- (float)
    echo $arr[$i].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Я думаю, вопрос не о том, как преобразовать целое число в вещественное.

Comment: Если целое преобразовывать в вещественное, разве у такого числа дробная часть не нулевой будет?

Comment: for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $arr[$i] = (float)rand(1, 100); //<--- (float)
    echo $arr[$i].'<br>';
}

Тип поменялся, но дробная часть нулевая (16,0) и все числа массива так выводит